# How to initialize specific members of a C-struct in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am writing a C++ struct which contains a C-struct.  The C-struct is included by other .c files, so I cannot change it to C++.

I want to make sure that every member is of the c++ struct is initialized.
So I have used in-class initialization and constructor initilizer where needed:

```
struct CppStruct 
{
    CStruct pod {};    // initialize all members to 0
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;

    CppStruct()  
    { }

    CppStruct(int another_val) 
        : i(another_val) 
    { }
};
```

This initializes all the members of the CStruct to zeroes.
Zeroes are fine for most members of the c-struct,
but unfortunately, it also contains a C-enum whithout a zero-value:

```
// C-header
enum Color {  // no '0' entries here!
  red = 1,
  yellow = 2;
};

struct CStruct { // this struct can potentially contain a lot of members
    int i;
    int j;
    Color col;
    int m;
    int n;
};
```

The only way I have found to write the constructor is this, but this theoretically sets the `pod.col` member twice:

```
    CppStruct()  
    { pod.col = Color::red; }

    CppStruct(int another_val) 
        : i(another_val) 
    { pod.col = Color::red; }
```

Is there anyway I can override the initialization of selected members of the `pod`, without having to specify all its members?

e.g. I tried this but it does not compile:

```
    CppStruct()  : pod.col(Color::red) {}
```

The following is legal, but I want to avoid it,
in case the CStruct is changed/shuffled by another colleague:

```
    CppStruct()  : pod{0,0,Color::red,0,0} {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **best** way I think is to just overwrite the `col` value inside the constructor, don't worry about multiple initializations, as it's just an enum, not a massive object, so the performance difference is somewhat nothing (unless you are really desperate for performance).

A quick and dirty way to achieve initialization the way you wanted is to create a static function that would return a default `CStruct` like that:

```
struct CppStruct 
{
    CStruct pod {};    // initialize all members to 0
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;

    CppStruct()
        : pod(_get_default_pod())
    { }

    CppStruct(int another_val) 
        : i(another_val), pod(_get_default_pod())
    { }
        
private:
    static inline CStruct _get_default_pod() {
        CStruct pod {};
        pod.col = Color::red;
        return pod;
    };
};
```

Comment: Could also do `CStruct pod = _get_default_pod();` in the class body itself so you don't forget to initialize it in a constructor. Also can (should?) make `_get_default_pod` `constexpr`.

Comment: @N.Shead can't make it `constexpr` for my compiler, it complains that the body is not a return-only statement, so it appears it doesn't support NRVO

Comment: That is a requirement of C++11 which got lifted in future revisions; the question is marked C++17, so I assumed that that would be fine. (NRVO has nothing to do with it.)

Comment: Although I see some value in this solution, `_get_default_pod()` still initializes `pod` is and assigns `red` to `pod.col`.  Do you think there's any way of avoiding the extra assignment?

Comment: @GrimFandango if you use C++17 and you make it `constexpr` as @N.Shead suggested, I would expect the compiler to initialize `pod` in place

Comment: Though hard to tell exactly

Comment: @AlexLarionov, but `constexpr` is only activated if you explicitly write it, like:
`CppStruct() : pod(constexpr _get_default_pod()) { }`
Is this the right syntax?

Comment: @GrimFandango I meant to make the static function definition `constexpr`. I just tested the [Assembly of this version](https://godbolt.org/z/PKoKM8), and it seems that with `-O2` optimization flag on GCC it does indeed initialize `pod` in place.

Comment: @GrimFandango but funny enough if you just do this assignment inside the constructor, like you've already tried `pod.col = Color::red;`, then with `-O2` optimization the result is the same, it's initialized in place